# KnockoutJS Value Binding Dynamic

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

Is there a way to bind dynamically to an object in knockout such as this:

```
<label data-bind="attr:{for:$data.name}, text:$data.prettyName"></label>
                                            <!-- ko if:$data.isTextBox-->
                                                <input data-bind="attr:{id:$data.name,value:$parent.currentDocument().values[$data.name]}" type="text"></input>
                                            <!-- /ko -->
```

Or is there any other way to handle k/v binding?
values is defined as {} and as the overall type changes values[$data.name] is created.

Comment: I guess you should use unwrapped values for names and id: <label data-bind="attr: { for: $data.name() }..."></label> . The same thing for  input element: <input data-bind="attr: {id: $data.name(), ...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` should be binded without `attr`

```
<input data-bind="attr:{id:$data.name}, value:$parent.currentDocument().values[$data.name]" type="text"></input>
```